# Convert Extern C to Inline ASM

Tags: c++, winapi, assembly

I have a C++ project that calls a extern function located in a .asm (MASM) file. Is there any way I can inline the MASM code inside of the C++ file instead of having to having to use a seperate .asm file?

.asm file

```
.data

.code

ZwReadVirtualMemory proc
    mov r10, rcx
    mov eax, 3Fh
    syscall
    ret
ZwReadVirtualMemory endp

end
```

Here is the C++ file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" NTSTATUS ZwReadVirtualMemory(HANDLE hProcess, void* lpBaseAddress, void* lpBuffer, SIZE_T nSize, SIZE_T* lpNumberOfBytesRead = NULL);

int main() {

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 14648);
    if (!hProcess)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    int intBuffer = 0;
    void* lpBaseAddress = 0;
    SIZE_T lpNumberOfBytesRead = 0;

    NTSTATUS status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, (PVOID)0x10ad0000, &intBuffer, sizeof(int), &lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    cout << "ZwRVM returned " << dec << status << endl;
    cout << "intBuffer = " << dec << intBuffer << endl;
    cout << "lpNumberOfBytesRead = " << lpNumberOfBytesRead << endl;

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: You could use inline assembly for that, but it's really uggly to do so.  A separate assembly file is strictly clearer and a better idea.

Comment: Why? Would I have to handle anything differently if I inlined it? The assembly code itself would not need to be modified, correct? @fuz

Comment: first of all inline asm only for x86. it not supported for x64 - so you just restrict self for 32 bit only. then `mov eax, 3Fh` in `ZwReadVirtualMemory` is incorrect. this value different for different windows versions. you must not do this at all

Comment: anyway use separate asm file in project the best solution.

Comment: @RbMm `first of all inline asm only for x86. it not supported for x64 -` that is a limitation of Visual C++. All the others clang, gcc and icc don't have that issue as far as I know

Comment: @PeterT - yes, but i sure that OP definitely use *CL.EXE* compiler

Comment: @RbMm I thought I'd just mention it for completeness sake, since you can easily just install clang and just switch the compiler in Visual Studio to it within minutes if inline asm is important.

Comment: @RichardCullins No, but then it's no longer portable to other compilers and there is no clean separation between assembly code and C code.

Comment: @RbMm I'm aware that the syscall will differ between windows versions, but I'm hardcoding it for a test. I'll deal with that issue later. I've installed Clang and and trying to use that at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Certain C/C++ compilers support non-standard inline assembly blocks `asm` or `__asm__`. They can be used to incorporate portions of assembler code into regular functions or methods.

Your code sample clearly points at using a WinAPI (thus Windows as target platform) and Visual Studio as a compiler (`stdafx.h` being the most unportable piece). However, Visual Studio 2010 and later updates stopped supporting inline assembly for 64-bit targets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93%28VS.100%29.aspx

Your options:

1. Compile MASM file into a separate object file and link it later with the rest of the program.
2. Use Intel Compiler for Windows. It supports inline assembler and is meant to be a drop-in replacement for Microsoft compilers on Windows, however I do not know how much extra porting effort will be required.
3. The only bit from your assembler file that is not directly accessible from C/C+ is issuing the `syscall` machine instruction. If you find an [intrinsic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) function for that instruction that is supported by MS VS, you can use it instead of an inline assembly block. However, I cannot find one [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/alphabetical-listing-of-intrinsic-functions). Intel's intrinsics are [no better](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/).

Comment: *"`stdafx.h` being the most unportable piece"* - *stdafx.h* is - presumably - just a header file. There is nothing unportable about using header files. Even if you set up your compiler to use it to generate a precompiled header, the code is still portable. Besides, your bullet point 3 is wrong: There are also 2 `mov` instructions, to load values into specific registers. That is also not doable from C or C++, yet part of the `syscall` contract.

Comment: Actually the `asm` declaration is part of the standard, though what it does (if anything) is implementation defined. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm

Comment: @IInspectable, `mov` instructions are necessary, yes, but having an intrinsic for a single instruction usually means that it is now the compiler's task to find right registers for the task. One less place for a human to make a mistake.

Comment: This interpretation is based on the existence of a hypothetical kernel call intrinsic, that takes the selectors as arguments. Since that hypothetical intrinsic does not exist, `syscall` isn't the only instruction that cannot be expressed in C or C++, and bullet point 3 is simply incorrect as written.